# Django translations inside included HTML template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am including a file in a Django webpage using this:

```
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

This included HTML file contains `trans` tags, which are not being translated. In fact, Django returns a TemplateSyntaxError:

```
Invalid block tag: 'trans'
```

I know that the `include` tag does not process the included file. I've seen other questions ask about overriding blocks in included files, to which the answers mentioned that this is not possible in Django. I presume this is the same problem.

Is there a way to force Django to process included files, or some other tag that achieves this? Or maybe Python code, as a last resort?

**Important note:** I cannot simply add the footer in a base file and `extend` from this base, because I already have a base, which is actually the one trying to include footer.html (I have several base templates for different sub-sites, but all of which should use the same footer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside footer.html you need to load i18n

```
{% load i18n %}
```

quote from the docs:

> As with all template tags, this tag needs to be loaded in all
>   templates which use translations, even those templates that extend
>   from other templates which have already loaded the i18n tag.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that simple thing... Thank you very much! I suspect the `include` limitation will bite me in other things, though, but that is another matter entirely.